# A point topology problem about condensation points with a fantastic answer.

Tags: general-topology

Assume that $S\subset R^n$ and assume that $S$ is not countable.Let $T$ denote the set of condensation points of S.Prove that:$S\bigcap T$ is not countable.
The answer is so fantastic to me.It just write that $S=(S\bigcap T)\bigcup (S-T)$ and since both of these sets are countable thus S is countable if we assume that $S\bigcap T$ is countable.
And this makes a contradiction.(I know the result that $S-T$ is countable)
I wonder whether there is any natrual way to prove the problem before?
(A point is said to be condensation point fo $S$ if every n-Ball $B(x)$ has the property that $B(x)\bigcap S$ is not countable)

The whole problem is that Assume that $S\subset R^n$ and assume that $S$ is not countable.Let $T$ denote the set of condensation points of S.
Prove that:

1.$S-T$ is countable.
2.$S\bigcap T$ is not countable
3.$T$ is closed.
4.$T$  contains no isolated points.

This is a problem from mathematical analysis (apostol) page 67 3.24
This give a way to prove Cantor-Bendixon theorem.

Comment: *I wonder whether there is any natrual way to prove this?* --- What does "this" refer to? You have made several assertions. Are you looking for a "natural way" to prove the Cantor-Bendixson theorem (I know 3 widely different methods to prove it -- Cantor and Bendixson's transfinite iteration of the derived set operator, Lindelöf's use of condensation points, Hausdorff's use a maximal dense-in-itself set) or are you not familiar with the [Cantor-Bendixson theorem](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Cantor-Bendixson+theorem%22)?

Comment: Are you saying that you know that $S - T$ is countable? Are you asking how to show that a union of disjoint countable sets is countable?

Comment: I apologize for the unclear expression!I want to know how to prove $S\bigcap T$ is not countable if I am not aware of that $S=（S\bigcap T）\bigcup (S-T)$ I tried to assume that S is countable and make some contradiction (but I don't know this fact $S=（S\bigcap T）\bigcup (S-T)$)I hope someone can maybe find a way to prove this instead of this way.And I am truly willing to know more about the methods to prove Cantor and Bendixson's theorem!

Comment: @钱珺凯 This is a very elementary and fundamental fact that you are trying to avoid using.  It seems unlikely there is a way to avoid using this decomposition.

Comment: It’s kind of like asking to prove the fundamental theorem of arithmetic without using the associative property of multiplication.  Maybe one could do it in some roundabout way, but you have to ask yourself, “to what end?”

Comment: All right.Thank you!